# Can an objective-c class conform to a swift protocol?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Let's say we have a protocol in swift as:

```
@objc protocol MySwiftyProtocol: NSObject {}
```

Can an objective-c class conform to a swift protocol?

Like:

```
@interface MyObjcClass : NSObject <MySwiftyProtocol>
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Of course I have tried it. :)  However, I could not determine from my tests if the issue was my implementation (as above), or that it was simply is not supported.

Comment: And what was the answer?

Comment: Can anyone supply a link to Apple documentation on this?

Comment: _I could not determine from my tests if the issue was my implementation (as above), or that it was simply is not supported._ Show how have you done it to get a better response soon.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID122

Answer (score 2):

Yes they can, (but only in the .m file).

Comment: Instead of deleting [you error question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46621239/), it's more useful to marking it as a duplicate the target dupe I linked to. You write it yourself: _"However, I could have never found that question because of the wording of its title"_: this is probably the main use case for keeping duplicates non-deleted: to help users searching for other wordings actually finding the answer (that might be hidden under a similar but not entirely equivalent title). I would suggest re-opening you question so we can properly mark it as a duplicate for the target.

Comment: The link is dead