# What is the best way to determine the type (actually subclass) of an Error thrown by a Swift function?

Tags: swift

Assume you can only see the "header" for a compiled swift class called VendingMachine. As follows:

```
class VendingMachine {
    func getFreeRandomSnack() throws -> Snack
}
```

How would you determine the subclass of Error thrown?

Assume that the implementor used the following subclass for errors (but you as the reader don't know this):

```
enum VendingMachineError: Error {
    case invalidSelection
    case insufficientFunds(coinsNeeded: Int)
    case outOfStock
}
```

Without introspection, how would you ever know what you could catch?

If you have to use introspection, what is the best way to determine the exhaustive list of possible Error subclasses thrown?

Comment: Why do you need to know this? The author of the function is always free to start throwing new types of errors in a future version of the API.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to determine which errors are possibly thrown.