# How to conform a protocol made in a Swift library in a Objective-C project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have to implement the skeleton effect on a Objective-C project. I found many libraries on Objc but they did not perform what I want to do. I found this Swift library -- https://github.com/Juanpe/SkeletonView.
I made it work with any UIView using bridging header with this extension.

Swift File

```
extension UIView {
    @objc public func showWaitingLoader() {
        let gradient = SkeletonGradient(baseColor: UIColor(red:0.9, green:0.9, blue:0.9, alpha:1))
        let animation = SkeletonAnimationBuilder().makeSlidingAnimation(withDirection: GradientDirection.leftRight)
        self.showAnimatedGradientSkeleton(usingGradient: gradient, animation: animation)
    }

    @objc public func hideWaitingLoader(){
        self.hideSkeleton(reloadDataAfter: true)
    }
}
```

Objective-C file

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SkeletonView-Swift.h"
#import "Skeleton-Swift.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *firstLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *container;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _firstLabel.isSkeletonable = YES;
    [_container showWaitingLoader];
}
```

It worked really well. But now I need this effect in a collection (TableView). The library says to conform a view controller with the next protocol, which is the next.

```
public protocol SkeletonTableViewDataSource: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numSections(in collectionSkeletonView: UITableView) -> Int
    func collectionSkeletonView(_ skeletonView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    func collectionSkeletonView(_ skeletonView: UITableView, cellIdentifierForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> ReusableCellIdentifier
}
```

But I don't know how to use this protocol on my Header file (Objective-C project). Like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SkeletonView-Swift.h"
#import "Skeleton-Swift.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <SkeletonTableViewDataSource>

@end
```

Apparently I can not use this protocol one my header file according to a previous question.

[Can an objective-c class conform to a swift protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45618508/can-an-objective-c-class-conform-to-a-swift-protocol)

So I want to know how could I use this protocol so I can conform it in my ViewController.m and have the skeleton effect in my tableview.

Comment: You have to use the `@protocol` declaration.

Comment: Would you mind to provide an example :D ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you cannot.  Swift can generate objective C compatible thunks if you use the `@objc` attribute, but while Swift is aware of Objective C, Objective C is not otherwise aware of Swift.  You can solve this problem by writing a Swift ViewController that conforms to your protocol and then mark the entire class as `objc`.  This way your objective C class can override all of the methods that actually implement the Swift protocol without actually knowing about the Swift protocol.

Comment: Wow thank you for your explanation . Luckily I found a library in Swift the supports Objc and finally I could achieve the skeleton effect. I'm gonna mark this answer as an accepted because it helped me understand a little better interoperability in iOS. Thank you :D . The library I´m gonna use is https://github.com/malkouz/ListPlaceholder in case anyone wants this effect in their objc project .